# viewing requests sent by curl

Tags: php, curl

How can I see requests that are sent out by curl? For example;

I'm getting a page and print out the contents, but this page also requests another page that I would like the contents of.

How would I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "see"? I don't understand.

Comment: You want to see the **results** of a cURL request, or the *request* that cURL sends out? That's not quite clear.

Comment: I basically mean, I use curl_get to view http://page.com and page.com loads page.com/2.php, I want to view the contents of 2.php even though I don't know it's requesting this. I found out it's being requested by using livehttpheaders. THanks

Comment: @Hussan, it depends on how the page is being redirected.If is using a location header, curl will pick it up. if it is using javascript, or meta refresh, you will need to parse the page first.

Comment: If it's a re-direct then CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION = 1 will help if it doesn't pick it up.

Comment: It's not a redirect, it's a ajax get

Answer (score 1):

If it's header information you're after...

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
```

and

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
```

will return the header information in the results which you will then have to process with either string functions or regular expressions.

eg

```
preg_match_all('#HTTP/\d\.\d.*?$.*?\r\n\r\n#ims', $curl_result, $header_matches);
$headers = split("\r\n", str_replace("\r\n\r\n", '', array_pop($header_matches[0])));
$curl_result = preg_replace('#HTTP/\d\.\d.*?$.*?\r\n\r\n#ims', '',$curl_result);
```

From there you can locate any offending header entries in the array $headers